# react project not picking up html tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I created a react project using

```
npx create-react-app
```

and when i edit the code in App.js and put `"<h1>"` or html tags, it just have no effect. It renders the text in plain paragraph type not in heading type. What is wrong with it? Can anyone help?

I tried deleting app.css file, it had no effect, tried updating it and etc etc. My react project uses tailwind css but i dont think so tailwind is messing up with the project since i have made tons of project using tailwind css and never experienced anything like this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Without any relevant code, it's hard for someone to troubleshoot your issue. Please post the code so folks here can check it for syntax errors, and also, are did you run `npm start`, did you check that the file is saved, and did the page refresh when you made changes?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior if you are in fact using Tailwind, since Tailwind [automatically removes styles from headings](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#headings-are-unstyled) as well as a few other elements.

You can style your headings individually using the `class` attribute, or style them all at once [using the `@apply` directive](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-base-styles#using-css).